# Google+ interactive post - How to add callbacks for buttons?

Tags: javascript, callback, google-plus

I'm using the [Google+ interactive post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) feature where the posting window offers a `close` and `share` button.
How can I detect which one the user clicked? I can't find callbacks in their [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#javascript_api) - is it possible to add *custom ones*?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the type of callbacks that you desire are not provided. The only callback for the button is the callback that handles signing in the user via the interactive post button, which provides the access token and other information in its response. Listening to that callback would let you know if they authorized your app, but not that they necessarily followed through with the share.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onShare` option as provided below

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var options = {
    clientid: GooglePlus.getClientId(),
    contenturl: data.shareURL,
    calltoactionlabel: "SHARE",
    calltoactionurl: data.shareURL,
    cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
    prefilltext: "",
    callback: function(response){},
    onshare: function(response){ 
        if(response.status === 'completed') {
            if(response.action && response.action === 'cancelled') {
                deferred.reject( response );
            } else {
                deferred.resolve( response );
            }
        }
    }
};

$window.gapi.interactivepost.render($event.target, options);
```